# Python not running every second

Tags: python

```
import threading
import time

def cold_temp():
    # Open the file that we viewed earlier so that python can see what is in it. Replace the serial number as before. 
    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-021571bf69ff/w1_slave") 
    # Read all of the text in the file. 
    text = tfile.read() 
    # Close the file now that the text has been read. 
    tfile.close() 
    # Split the text with new lines (\n) and select the second line. 
    secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
    # Split the line into words, referring to the spaces, and select the 10th word (counting from 0). 
    temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
    # The first two characters are "t=", so get rid of those and convert the temperature from a string to a number. 
    temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
    # Put the decimal point in the right place and display it. 
    temperature = temperature / 1000 
    return temperature

output = cold_temp()    
f = open('/var/www/html/coldtemp.html', 'w')
print >> f, output
f.close()
cold_temp()
```

I've tried the above and a simple

```
def cold_temp():
    while True:
        # Open the file that we viewed earlier so that python can see what is in it. Replace the serial number as before. 
        tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-021571bf69ff/w1_slave") 
        # Read all of the text in the file. 
        text = tfile.read() 
        # Close the file now that the text has been read. 
        tfile.close() 
        # Split the text with new lines (\n) and select the second line. 
        secondline = text.split("\n")[1] 
        # Split the line into words, referring to the spaces, and select the 10th word (counting from 0). 
        temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
        # The first two characters are "t=", so get rid of those and convert the temperature from a string to a number. 
        temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
        # Put the decimal point in the right place and display it. 
        temperature = temperature / 1000 
        return temperature

        output = cold_temp()    
        f = open('/var/www/html/coldtemp.html', 'w')
        print >> f, output
        f.close()
        time.sleep(1)
```

I am wanting to run the script every second.  Both of the above run once then end.

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: What exactly is happening? Does the script crash? Does it run every 1.1 seconds or not all?

Comment: Show us `do something`.

Comment: Why is it so important this is ran every second

Comment: It checks temperature. It runs once and does not continue

Comment: Check the [python generator to return series of times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10658295/346478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop is in the wrong place. I took the liberty of changing your code to use `with` clauses which is the more standard way to open files but it will break if you have a really old python.

```
import threading
import time

def cold_temp():
    # Open the file that we viewed earlier so that python can see what is in it. Replace the serial number as before. 
    with open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-021571bf69ff/w1_slave") as tfile:
        # skip first line, keep second line
        next(tfile)
        secondline = next(tfile)
    # Split the line into words, referring to the spaces, and select the 10th word (counting from 0). 
    temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9] 
    # The first two characters are "t=", so get rid of those and convert the temperature from a string to a number. 
    temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:]) 
    # Put the decimal point in the right place and display it. 
    temperature = temperature / 1000 
    return temperature

while True:
    output = cold_temp()    
    with open('/var/www/html/coldtemp.html', 'w') as f:
        print >> f, output
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works perfectly.  Decided to test by putting the thermometer into my mouth then ice cold water.  great

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sched` module to schedule something to run repeatedly, whether it be every two hours or every one second.

If your function takes longer than one second to run (unlikely for just checking the temp.) then you'll have a delay.

You'll also see some "drift" in the time due to the time it takes your function to run as it's repeatedly scheduled. All of the tiny "bits" of time it takes your function to run will eventually add up.

e.g. -

```
import sched, time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def some_function():

    print time.time()
    s.enter(1, 0, some_function)

s.enter(1, 0, some_function)
s.run()
```

Comment: Also there are 5 arguments required for `s.enter`

Answer (score 1):

The first one runs once because you haven't given it any way to run repeatedly. The second one hits a `return` which exits the function (and thus the loop) before it even has the chance to output anything. Remove the `return` and just use `temperature` for the value of `output`.

Comment: Throws no errors but is not writing the output to html file

Comment: Don't call `output = cold_temp()`. It's recursion: `cold_temp` keeps calling itself forever and never gets to the output part. Just print the value of `temperature`.

Comment: still does not write.. 

        `temperature = temperature / 1000 
   
        f = open('/var/www/html/coldtemp.html', 'w')
        print >> f, temperature
        f.close()
        time.sleep(1)`

Comment: If you open with `'w'` instead of `'a'` it will overwrite the value every time instead of appending a new one. Is that what you want? If not and the temperature isn't changing you won't be able to tell if it keeps writing.

Comment: It was overwriting I thought, as it was showing changes but not creating additional files or lines in the file.  But I have deleted that file and the script is not creating it anymore to write to it whereas before i tried to loop the script, it was working fine.

Comment: Use some basic debugging statements: add some print statements or use `pdb`. These would have also helped with your earlier problems.